# Выделить словарь из списка

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

в первой части одной из задач результат вышел такой:

```
[(1, {'название': 'телевизор', 'цена': 1000, 'количество': 2, 'ед': 'шт'}), (2, {'название': 'магнитофон', 'цена': 3000, 'количество': 2, 'ед': 'шт'})]
```

То есть это произвольно введенные элементы, где выходит вопрос введите название, цену и тд, а пользователь вводит. Их может быть сколько угодно.
Как теперь дальше сделать, чтобы из этих элементов сформировался словарь, а на выходе получилось:

```
'название': ['телевизор', 'магнитофон'],
'цена': [1000, 3000],
'количество': [2, 2],
'ед': ['шт']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

делайте в лоб:

```
arr = [(1, {'название': 'телевизор', 'цена': 1000, 'количество': 2, 'ед': 'шт'}), (2, {'название': 'магнитофон', 'цена': 3000, 'количество': 2, 'ед': 'шт'})]

res = dict()

for obj in arr:
    for props in obj[1].items():
        elem = res.get(props[0], [])
        elem.append(props[1])
        res[props[0]] = elem

print(res)
```

внутренняя начинка с `get` эквивалентна

```
    if props[0] in res:
        res[props[0]].append(props[1])
    else:
        res[props[0]] = [props[1]]
```